# How to convert NSArray's element type in Swift

Tags: swift

I created a `NSFetchedResultsController`

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "User")
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "recordName", ascending: true)]

        _frcU = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: _managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        _frcU!.delegate = self
        _frcU!.performFetch(nil)
```

then in the `numberOfRowsInSection` method, I want to check the row number in the first section

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

            var numberOfRowsInSection = 0
            if _frcU {
/*here something  wrong -> */ let o: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo = _frcU?.sections().firstObject as NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo
                numberOfRowsInSection = o.numberOfObjects
            }
        }
```

but it says: ST6 (firstObject) **does not conform to protocol 'NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo'**

Why, how should I rephrase it?

Comment: Can you try changing `as` to `as?` when casting the return value of `firstObject` to a `NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo`?

Comment: I tried it, does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

working solution is:

```
numberOfRowsInSection = ((_frcU!.sections as NSArray).firstObject as NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo).numberOfObjects
```

there is two basic difference

1) ! mark

2) "casting" to NSArray

Answer (score 0):

Here how you can do it:

```
    let sectionInfo = _frcU.sections[section] as NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo
    let numberOfRowsInSection = sectionInfo.numberOfObjects
```

You can take a look at default Master-Detail Application template in xCode. Project can be created in Swift so there is a lot of stuff to learn about how things are done in Swift.

Comment: Just for my education: what is the difference between your working example and OP's? Is it the `_frcU` instead of `_frcU?`, or using array notation instead of `firstObject`?

Comment: `_frcU?` checks for `nil` before invoking next operation but _frcU should be optional for this. It you define `_fcrU` as `NSFetchedResultController?` then I should add it as well. `firstObject` is a method in `NSArray` class which you can call after casting which make code longer and harder to read.

Comment: Right, I'm familiar with the optionals and the `firstObject` method, I was just curious what specifically caused János version to fail, and yours to work. Thanks!